# Moving data between base project and Azure Functions Cosmos DB Trigger project (both within same Xamarin.Forms solution)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I have set up an Azure Functions Cosmos DB Trigger project within the umbrella of a Xamarin.Forms solution that holds multiple other projects. The trigger project if fully functional and recognizes changes made to my Cosmos DB database. My plan was to use the trigger project, more specifically, the trigger function, to notify my base project that a change had been made in the DB and use a function in my base project to ping the DB, collect the changes, and update the interface. The trouble is I cannot seem to connect what is happening in my trigger function to my base project.

I have tried inputting a MessagingCenter notification directly within the trigger function and tying it to a subscription in the base project, with no avail. I have also tried creating a static variable in the trigger project, and pairing it with static property changed event handlers in the base project, which also failed. I've referenced the trigger project in base project, and the reverse, on the off chance that there was some kind of interference for a particular directional flow. Both of the MessagingCenter and event listener options were tested within project lines, amongst test classes, and worked just fine, so I'm confident I didn't bungle the set up.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can approach fixing it?

[Edit:
I think I've narrowed the issue to the projects running concurrent but separate instances. I placed a static variable in the base project, and exposed it to the dependent trigger project by assigning it to a value within the trigger function. When I ran the program, I initialized the static variable in the base project to 0, and then I incremented it by way of a function in the base project (by this point the trigger function had not been engaged at all and the static variable in the base project had been incremented to 1). I then engaged the trigger function by making a change in my DB, and when breakpoint stopped the trigger function at the spot it was going to assign the static variable, the value assigned was 0, even though it had already been incremented to 1 in the base project. I then called and same increment function in base, and the variable jumped from 1 to 2 in the base project, while remaining 0 again in the trigger project. For some reason the base project and the trigger project were watchin two different static variables, despite referencing the same one.]

Comment: "My plan was to use the trigger project, more specifically, the trigger function, to notify my base project that a change had been made in the DB and use a function in my base project to ping the DB, collect the changes, and update the interface" - The Trigger already receives the changes (full documents), why don't you directly send those changes to the other component instead of notifying the other component and forcing it to read the changes again?

Comment: Apart from Matias's suggestion, If you're referencing trigger and base project in each other, there'll be a infinite reference loop, don't do that. And check for sure that your trigger do fired after db change when referenced in your base project. Also, it will be helpful to locate the problem if you can provide more details about where/how you're using the MessagingCenter/event handler in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MatiasQuaranta, sorry for the my late response. You're right, that definitely makes more sense, but my challenge would still be to expose the trigger response, located in my trigger project, to my base project.

Comment: @Nicole Lu - MSFT, I'm certain my trigger fires, any changes made directly to my DB always hit the breakpoints in my trigger function. I'm certain my Messaging is ok too, I've tested the intra-project formatting repeatedly with success.

Comment: @SandroMijatovic How do these projects exist? If they are running inside the same project, you can simply register a DI dependency that acts as a buffer or Pub/Sub medium, the Trigger can push data into this DI object and your other project can subscribe to changes. If they live/execute in separate instances, you would need to link them through something like a Queue, you can push documents into the Queue and have a QueueTrigger on the other project?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta They exist within the same solution, but are in separate project folders. I've listed the base project as a dependency in the trigger project, thinking that would force them to run together, but they are completely siloed. I'm not so familiar with DI dependency or QueueTriggers, but I will definitely look into them, I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, the best approach would be to receive the changes on the Trigger, and since they already contain all the document information, notify the other component within the same project through some signal.

The signaling mechanism could leverage the [Azure Functions DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) to maintain a single object that could act as a Pub/Sub where the Trigger would just publish the documents to and the other component can subscribe to.